# How to make a different Calendar Table Model in Java?

Tags: java, swing, calendar, defaulttablemodel

I have been trying to make a calendar, currently I have a simple Gregorian calendar where one month is divided into four weeks. As I understand this is a DefaultTableModel. Are there any other models I could use or any other ways to make my calendar into one row of one month, but not grid type? Or should I use some addRow/setRowCount/ect. method? If so, how?
This is a small piece of code:

```
String [] columns = {"Sun","Mon","Tue","Wed","Thu","Fri","Sat"};
model = new DefaultTableModel(null,columns);
JTable table = new JTable(model);
JScrollPane pane = new JScrollPane(table);
```

Thank you in advance!

Comment: By the way, you may find `DayOfWeek` class helpful.

Comment: @BasilBourque, could you elaborate on that? Sorry, I am not that good in all of this...

Comment: You can track the days of the weeks using [`DayOfWeek`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/DayOfWeek.html) enum objects. Also, those objects can [automatically localize](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/DayOfWeek.html#getDisplayName(java.time.format.TextStyle,java.util.Locale)): `DayOfWeek.getDisplayName( TextStyle.SHORT , Locale.CANADA_FRENCH )`

Comment: Also, you can find many examples of a calendar in a JTable by [searching the internet](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=JTable+calendar) and [searching Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=JTable+calendar).

Comment: I will try, thanks.